# What is the speed and temperature profile of the boundary layer at the stagnation point?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics, fluid-mechanics, flight-mechanics, aerospace

At the statgnation point where the air velocity is zero, what is the shape of the velocity and temperature profile of the boundary layer? Is the velocity profile of the boundary layer in the form of a straight line (because the air velocity is zero at all points)?
what about temperature profile ?

Comment: By definition the boundary layer begins at the the stagnation point, so its thickness there is simply zero. Or do you mean something else?